# class="btn-group-justified" widens my page, same classes included in style tag don't work. how come?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page which breaks down as follows:

```
 <div class="container-fluid" style="min-width:768px">
    <div id="main-sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main-frame"></div>
      <div id="supplementary-sidebar"></div>
      <div id="content-container"></div>
        <!-- ALL THE INTERESTING CODE GOES HERE -->
        <div id="content" class="row"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
 </div>
```

The widths of all the elements in container fill the screen width.
The main-sidebar's width is set to auto.
The main-frame is set to min-width of 72.65%.
The supplementary-sidebar is at 20% of the parent main-frame.
The content-container is at 80% of the parent main-frame.

Basically I want the main-sidebar to be as big as it need to be,
and then have the main-frame fill up the rest of the parent page.

I succeeded at this by accident and have pinpointed the Twitter Bootstrap class that gets the job done. The screen will not fill if I remove it. This is:

```
<div class="btn-group-justified" style=""></div>
```

I have tried many different lines of code (included below), which were attempts at doing this consciously. But at this point I can't really go  much further.
Does anybody know why this forces the main-frame to fill up the screen?

Here are my attempts:

```
<!---
    NOTHING HERE WORKS

    <div style="width:100%">&nbsp;</div>

    <div style="display:table;width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;border-collapse:seperate;display: block;"></div>

    <div style="display:table;width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;border-collapse:seperate;display: block;">&nbsp;</div>

    <div id="spreader" class="row" style="">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="spreader"></div>
    #spreader{
      display:table;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-collapse:seperate;
      display: block;
    }
-->

<!--- THIS IS HOW I ORGINALLY GOT IT TO WORK
<div class="row" style="">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" style="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
-->
```

Here is the the screenshot showing the relevant bootstrap code. For some reason, this still works when I take border-collapse out. But if I include just this in a class like I did with `#spreader` above (and even if I include border-collapse) it will still not work.

[image: Twitter Bootstrap 3 .btn-group-justified]